# How to get values in dropdown list from database in icefaces?

Tags: icefaces

i just wanna list the list of employee names from database in the dropdown list using ice faces .  can anyone suggest me how to write the query in icefaces page to get the list of employees in the database . say table name is  "employee" .

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this. 
in your bean call your business class
e.g:

```
ArrayList<SelectItem> selectEmployees = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
ArrayList<Employee> employees = company.getEmployees();  //this one calls the EmployeeDAO to get the records from database.

for(int i = 0; i < employees.size(); i++){ 
  selectEmployees.add(new SelectItem(employes.get(i).getId(),employees.get(i).getName));
}
```

now you can use selectEmployees as the value of the selectOneMenu.